# Label content not updating WPF

Tags: wpf

i have a program that determines whether the device is connected to internet or not, when i start the program  the label tells if the device is connected or not, but when i disconnect or connect the device to internet, the label does not update, and i need to restart the app in order to see the label change.

here's my code

```
public static bool conexion()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var cliente = new WebClient())
                  using (cliente.OpenRead("http://google.com"))
                    return true;


            }

            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

        } 

    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (conexion() == true)
        {
            label.Content = "Esta conectado";
            label.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }

        else if(conexion() == false)
        {
            label.Content = "No esta conectado";
            label.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
```

Comment: You only check `http://google.com` once then never again. You should not call `conexion` in your constructor but create a timer in your form and call `conexion` only in your timer handler. And `conexion` should not be `static`.

Comment: i put the try catch inside the tick event of my timer and worked well for me thanks.